# What is the range of the fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is the group of rational numbers the fundamental group of some space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36775/is-the-group-of-rational-numbers-the-fundamental-group-of-some-space)

Given any group G,can we find a complex X whose fundamental group is G.If not,which kind of group satisfies this condition?

Comment: Yes, such space exists for any group. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space